# Is there any oracle solutions available for substrate based relay chain?

Tags: substrate-node, relay-chain

We have a Substrate based relay chain where we need to fetch external data like important documents and specific data using off-chain workers right now. But these OCW doesn't work for reaching consensus on data being fetched and put on chain. Is there any substrate based oracle available for relay-chain and not solo-chain or parachain?

Answer (score 1):

This link can help you: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-oracle

Here is a copy of the content linked:

In the blockchain context, an *oracle* is a way to bring real-world data onto the blockchain so that
it can be used by a decentralized application.

Oracles serve many purposes for application builders. For example:

- Most stablecoin designs use an oracle to bring in data of the exchange rate of assets, in order to
  peg their value to a real world currency.
- Synthetic assets use oracles as price feeds in order to determine if the underlying cryptocurrency
  can sufficiently collateralize the debt position.
- Prediction markets use oracles to decide the outcome of real world events and determine the payout
  of the prediction shares.
- Decentralized insurance markets use oracles to bring in information about whether a claim is valid
  or not.

Oracle solutions range from centralized and trusted to decentralized and game-theory based. On the
centralized end of the spectrum, an oracle could be a single account that has the authority to
dictate the real-world data on-chain. On the decentralized end, a
[complex game of "chicken"](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/03/28/schellingcoin-a-minimal-trust-universal-data-feed/)
can be played among various staked actors who risk getting slashed if they don't submit the same
data as everyone else. Solutions such as
[Chainlink](https://polkadot.network/chainlink-reaches-milestone-with-polkadot/) fit somewhere in
the middle, where the amount of trust you put into the reporting oracles can be adjusted based on
your preferences. A Chainlink
[Feed Pallet](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-polkadot/blob/master/pallet-chainlink-feed/README.md)
was recently released to allow smart contract applications across
Polkadot to access price reference data, made
available as a Substrate oracle pallet. [Acurast](https://acurast.com/) is another solution that
enables developers to define their off-chain data and computation requirements and receive the
outputs to the [Acurast Pallet](https://docs.acurast.com/integrations/substrate) and EVM or WASM
environments.

When using an oracle in your application you should be aware of the benefits and risks that are
baked into its specific model. As the Polkadot ecosystem develops and oracle parachains begin to appear, this article
will be updated with a comparison of the different solutions and the benefits and drawbacks that
each provide.